# Conditional Joint Distribution Concern

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Random variables $X$ and $Y$ are jointly distributed with density 
$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
3x & 0 <y<2x<2 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} 
$$
(i) Find $P\left(X<\frac{1}{2} \Big| Y < \frac{1}{2}\right)$
$$
P\left(X<\frac{1}{2} \Big| Y < \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{P\left(X < \frac{1}{2} \cap Y < \frac{1}{2} \right)}{P\left( Y < \frac{1}{2}\right)} \\ = \frac{ \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} 3x \, dx\,dy}{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{2} 3x \, dx\,dy}$$

Would someone help me out in verifying my work and if it has anything wrong to direct me to the right way.

Comment: @user365239 $$
P\left(X<\frac{1}{2} \Big| Y < \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{P\left(X < \frac{1}{2} \cap Y < \frac{1}{2} \right)}{P\left( Y < \frac{1}{2}\right)} \\ = \frac{ \int_{0}^{\frac{1
}{2}} \int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} 3x \, dxdy}{\int_{0}^{\frac{1
}{2}} \int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{1} 3x \, dxdy}$$ Is that correct ?

Comment: Do you an anwer in the book?

Comment: @ADAM yes that looks correct

Comment: You are right, I changed it  y is within x sorry

Comment: Thank you @user365239

Comment: Thank you @SatishRamanathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the denominator you should have

$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{1} 3x dx dy$

and in the numerator you should have
$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} 3x dy dx$

In other words, you should have $$\dfrac{\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}3x dx dy}{\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{1} 3x dx dy}$$